# Bison/Flex Parsing File

Tags: interpreter, bison, flex-lexer

I have recently tried using `GNU Bison` and `Flex` to write a interpreter. The text I want the interpreter to recognize is `print "Hello"` and I have tried the following:

`flex file:`

```
%{
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define YY_DECL extern "C" int yylex()
#include "gbison.tab.h"
%}
%%
[ \t\n]            ;
'\"'               return QUOTE;
[a-zA-Z0-9]+       { yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return STRING; }
%%
```

`bison file:`

```
%{
#include <cstdio> 
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" int yylex();
extern "C" int yyparse();
extern "C" FILE* yyin;

void yyerror (const char* s);
%}

%union {
  char* sval;
}

%token <sval> STRING
%token QUOTE
%%

str:
    STRING QUOTE STRING QUOTE
    {
       if (strcmp($1, "print") == 0)
       {
           cout << $3 << flush;
       }
       if (strcmp($1, "println") == 0)
       {
           cout << $3 << endl; 
       }
    }
    ;
%%

main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   FILE* input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   if (!input)
   {
      cout << "Bad input. Nonexistant file" << endl; 
      return -1;
   } 

   yyin = input;

   do 
   {
       yyparse();
   } while (!feof(yyin));

}
void yyerror(const char* s)
{
   cout << "Error. " << s << endl; 
   exit(-1);   
}
```

But when I pass `print "hello"` to the compiled program I get: 
`"Error. syntax error`

I think that the issue is the `STRING QUOTE STRING QUOTE` but I am not sure. What is exactly is going wrong? How would I get the interpreter to print `hello`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers are below, but I hope the following is more generally useful, as fishing instruction.

There are a variety of debugging tools which would help you. In particular, flex provides the `-d` flag:

> `-d, --debug`
>
> makes the generated scanner run in "debug" mode.  Whenever a pattern is recognized and the global variable `yy_flex_debug` is non-zero (which is the default), the scanner will write to `stderr` a line… ([flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Debugging-Options.html))

bison also provides a debug facility. ([bison manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Enabling-Traces.html))

> There are several means to enable compilation of trace facilities:
>
> - the macro `YYDEBUG`…
> - the option `-t` (POSIX Yacc compliant)…
> - the option `--debug` (Bison extension)…
> - the directive `%debug`…
>
> We suggest that you always enable the debug option so that debugging
> is always possible.
>
> …
> Once you have compiled the program with trace facilities, the way to
> request a trace is to store a nonzero value in the variable `yydebug`.
> You can do this by making the C code do it (in `main`, perhaps), or you
> can alter the value with a C debugger.

Also, remember that flex inserts an automatic rule which causes any otherwise unrecognized character to be echoed to the output. ("By default, any text not matched by a flex scanner is copied to the output" -- [Some simple examples](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Simple-Examples.html)) That's why you have the extra `"` in the error message being printed by your program:

```
"Error. syntax error
^
```

That's a bit subtle, though. Tracing `flex` would have shown you that more directly.

So, finally, the problem(s):

1. The flex pattern `'\"'` does not match a <kbd>"</kbd>. It matches <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>, because single quotes are not special to flex. That's definitely why your parse fails.
2. Fixing that will let your program parse a single command, but it will generate a syntax error if you try to give it two print commands in the same input. That's because bison always parses until it receives an `END` token from the lexer, and the lexer (by default) only provides an `END` token when it reaches the end of the input. You can change

   - the lexer behaviour (by sending `END` in other circumstances, for example a new-line) (**not** recommended)
   - the parser behaviour (by using `ACCEPT`) (possible, but rarely necessary)
   - the grammar, so that it recognizes any number of statements. (**recommended**)